# How to set an element's property using Funcunit in qunit window (test window)

Tags: jquery, qunit, funcunit

I am using FuncUnit with qunit to test an application. I would like to set `selected` property of an option of `<select>` menu to be `true` .

In `jQuery`, I could do something like

```
$('select#id option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true).change();
```

to achieve this. But, in funcunit,

```
S('select#id option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

selector finds the element and just get (not set) the value of prop `selected`. I want to set prop of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [comment](https://github.com/bitovi/funcunit/issues/57) from funcunit team - ***A user wouldn't be able to set the property of an option, they would just know to perform some action such as a click, drag, etc.***

so to achieve this we need to do

```
S.win.$('select#id option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

This runs jquery on test window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this instead?

`S('select#id option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');`

In jQuery this sets any attribute of a tag. For example, for a tag `<a href="#">Link</a>` you could set an attribute `href` like so: `$('a').attr('href', '#new-link');`). This should work for adding the `selected` property too in old XHTML style. Unsetting a property might be hard though.

The other option might be to use `click`, like so:

`S('select#id option:eq(0)').click();`

You should not even need to trigger `change`.

Comment: Yeah, I have already tried both attr() and click(), dint work. I am using `change` to manually trigger the event.